# go install not working

Tags: go, debian

I am using `go version go1.5.1 linux/amd64` on `debian 8.2 3.16.0-4-amd64`. I installed `golang` using https://golang.org/doc/install.

This is what i put in my `~/.profile` file

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/shivams/go/bin
```

Running `go env` on my machine is giving this output

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/shivams/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=""
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Directory structure inside `/home/shivams/go` is `{pkg,src,bin}`. Inside src directory it is like `test/hello.go`.

If i am in `src` dir and run `go run test/hello.go` it is running perfectly. Also if i run `go build test/hello.go` it will create one executable `hello` file in same directory.

But if i try to run `go install test/hello.go` then i get this error
`go install: no install location for .go files listed on command line (GOBIN not set)`. If i set `GOBIN` explicitly then i am not able to see this error.

From what i read my understanding is that if GOPATH is set there is no need to set GOBIN variable.

Am i missing anything here? This is the first time i am trying go and not able to get this working.

Comment: The go tools work on packages, not files. `go install test`

Comment: @JimB Yeah i understand this the hard way. :P

Comment: Alternatively, `go install` when inside the package directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @JimB states, `install` is a command designed for packages. Just to give you a clear example, here is what I get when I run the `go env` command.

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/Users/quazinafiulislam/Code/go/ogolang/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/quazinafiulislam/Code/go/ogolang"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=""
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

You will see that the `GOPATH` is set to my project root, `~/Code/go/ogolang`. Now, lets see whats inside my project root.

```
.
├── bin
├── pkg
│   └── darwin_amd64
└── src
    ├── bitbucket.org
    ├── github.com
    ├── golang.org
    ├── words
    └── wordtest
```

As you can see I have a couple of packages. One of them is `wordtest`. I can use a `go install` on the `words` or `wordtest` packages. So, lets run `go install words` and see what happens to the directory.

```
.
├── bin
│   └── words
├── pkg
│   └── darwin_amd64
└── src
    ├── bitbucket.org
    ├── github.com
    ├── golang.org
    ├── words
    └── wordtest
```

Now, we can see that we have a `words` binary created for us(inside the `bin` directory), and we can run it by invoking `./bin/words`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand that from @JimB comment but your answer explained it very clearly.

Answer (score 2):

According to `Games Brainiac` go install work on packages is correct. But let me add some details into it regarding creating packages using go install in main directory.

```
  .
  ├── bin
  │   └── app
  ├── pkg
  │   └── linux_amd64
  |         └── user
  |              └── handlers.a
  └── src
    ├── bitbucket.org
    ├── github.com
         └── user
              └── app
                   ├── main.go
                   └── handlers
                         └──handlers.go
```

Have a look at above directory structure, I have created a package in a folder handlers having source file `handlers.go` .And I wants to build that package, I will run `go build` inside handlers folder which just show our file has no compilation errors and returns nothing in that case.

To build a package with main file we need to run `go install` inside app folder. This will create handlers.a package object inside `$GOPATH/pkg` and executable file inside `$GOPATH/bin` with name of folder `(app in this case)` in which we have main.go file using package main.